# How to create form with context processor in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a form in my navigation bar. I am using a context processor for that.
I created themeChoice field in my UserProfile model. What I want to is when user click submit button, form will be save. I tried something but it did not work, my view prints nothing. How can I do that?

Note: my context processor is working.

**views.py**

```
def approval_context_processor(request):
...
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_theme = UserThemeChoiceform(request.POST)
            if form_theme.is_valid():
                user_who = request.POST.get('user_who', None)
                user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=user_who)
                print(user_who)
                form_theme.save()
                return redirect('home')

context= {
...
        'form': form_theme,
    }

    return context
```

**navigation.html**

```
<form method="POST" id="theme" action="#">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="user_who" value="{{ request.user }}" >
                                
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>

</form>
```

Comment: In `input` the value I think it's username, not user id, if you want `UserProfile.objects.get(id=...)`, you need `request.user.id` or `UserProfile.objects.get(username=...)`

Comment: You twist the meaning of a context processor here. A context processor validating a form? looks okay, but a context processor trying to redirect a user? Nope that won't work. A context processor is only supposed to return a dictionary which will be added to the context.